# sending cookie to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have implemented a simple login system using angular, express and passport.js into an existing project using the file structure and coding practices in [angular-passport](https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport).

At the moment, I successfully signup and login users. However when I refresh the page the users logs out. I understand I need to store a cookie on the browser in order to get this to work, and I also know how to implement this in code. My problem is where to put it.

In my `routes.js` I have the following:

```
var express = require('express'),
    auth = require('./auth');
var router = express.Router();


var tools = require('../controllers/tools');
router.get('/api/tools/category/:name', tools.category);
router.get('/api/tools/:id', tools.show);
router.get('/api/tools', tools.all);
router.post('/api/tools', tools.create);
// router.get('api/search/:term', tools.search);

var users = require('../controllers/users');
router.get('/api/users/:id', users.show);
router.get('/api/users', users.all);
router.post('/api/users', users.create);

// Session Routes
var session = require('../controllers/session');
router.get('/api/session', auth.ensureAuthenticated, session.session);
router.post('/api/session', session.login);
router.delete('/api/session', session.logout);

module.exports = router;
```

In the angular-passport repo the author adds another route at the end of the file:

```
router.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    if(req.user) {
        res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(req.user.user_info));
    }

    res.render('index.html');
});
```

However when I put this in my code this function is never called, as it already uses a one of the other routes declared before.. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Change the 1st line of your route:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
```

to this:

```
router.get('/*', function(req, res) {
```

your code never works cos nodejs don't know what `app` is. You never defined it.

UPDATE:

Change your server code to send the session cookie automatically with an expiration time:

```
// express/mongo session storage
app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'MEAN',
  store: new mongoStore({
    url: config.db,
    collection: 'sessions'
  }),
  cookie: { maxAge : 3600000 } //1 Hour <-----------
}));
```

or change the `passport.authenticate` function to send the cookie directly with expiration time.

https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport/blob/master/lib/controllers/session.js

```
exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) { return res.json(400, error); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return res.send(err); }
      res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(req.user.user_info), { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * hrs)} ); // <--
      return res.send(200); // <--
    });
  })(req, res, next);
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this block the rest of the routes? wouldn't everything simply go into this block of code? the `app.get` was just a typo in the question - sorry.

Comment: Ye dont use the middleware was my mistake. if you try `router.get('*', function(req, res) {` and go to http://yourdomain.com/somenotroutedlink works?

Comment: where? outside the middleware?

Comment: the `index.html'  is rendering if you go to http://yourdomain.com/somenotroutedlink ?

Comment: that's the thing, angular router is dealing with routing these requests, what I'm showing here is an API. the `res.render('index.html');` code was taken from the angular-passport repo however I don't think I need it.. I am only trying to respond with a cookie..

Comment: if your are useing https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport/blob/master/server.js as a example i will change some code to make it work with cookies. 5 min and i will update my answer